# Class and Methods

Tags: c#

I'm not sure what exactly to ask. I have created a class named `Car` when I click the Accelerate button on `Form1` I want it to accelerate 5 increments. I need to use the method Accelerate from the Car class to do this. I thought I was calling it correctly but nothing is working. I need simple answers as I am a beginner.

```
namespace Car_Class
{
    class Car
    {
        public string _year;
        public string _make;
        public double _speed;

        public Car(string year, string make, double speed)
        {
            _year = year;
            _make = make;
            _speed = 0;
        }

        public string Year
        {
            get { return _year; }
            set { }
        }

        public string Make
        {
            get { return _make; }
            set { }
        }

        public double Speed 
        {
            get { return _speed; }
            set { }
        }

        public double Accelerate()
        {
            return _speed += 5;
        }

        public double Brake()
        {
           return  _speed -= 5;
        }
    }
}
```

THEN the button....

```
namespace Car_Class
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void accButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string _year = "";
            string _make = "";
            int _speed = 0;

            Car acc = new Car(_year, _make, _speed);

            acc.Accelerate();

            currentspeedListBox.Text = ???????
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't make empty `set { }`s.

Comment: What do you mean not working? If you change `???????` to `acc.Speed.ToString();` what happens?

Comment: would a proper set be {_speed = value} or would value need to equal something?

Comment: Nothing happens when I add acc.Speed.ToString();

Comment: +1 - It's nice to see a beginner that has tried something before posting. Well done and good luck with your programming.

Comment: @Benjamin Keep in mind that when giving homework problems like this it's common for a teacher to provide a "shell" of an answer, leaving sections blank to be filled in by the student.  This may very well be the case here.  I'm unsure how much of this was actually written by the OP personally.

Comment: Thanks but there was no "shell"...Benjamin I appreciate your comment. I worked on this for hours. Like I said, I am beginner not a cheater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set currentspeedListBox.Text = acc.Speed.ToString()

Are you aware that you won't see an increasing speed but you'll only see 5? You are creating a new car when you hit the box (starts at 0) then you increment it by 5 when you accelerate. After everything is done, the car goes away and if you hit the button again the process starts over. (Creates a new car at speed 0, then increments it to 5)

If you want to keep seeing an increase in the textbox you need to put the car as a private variable in Form1, or you need to take the speed that you produced (5) and store it as a private variable outside of the method.

Edit:

```
private Car _car = new Car("","",0)

private void accButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _car.Accelerate();
     currentspeedListBox.Items.Add(car.Speed.ToString());
}
```

I assumed textbox even though it said otherwise. A ListBox is a container of many items, so it has an Items Property that has everything in it. The Text Property for a listBox refers to which one is currently selected in the listbox. Since there is nothing in the list box then nothing is selected (or appears). You need to add items to the ListBox, and in this case, the current acceleration.

Comment: I tried this and nothing appeared in the list box. Thanks for trying!

Comment: I was about to ask if if you're using a TextBox or a ListBox. If its a listbox you're not setting the text but you would be appending the items in the list box. I just changed my code above to act as though its a ListBox.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you are creating a new car each time you click the button

You need a car that is a member of the form

Form1 is a class just like Car is . Add A member _car of type car to it (Just after the class statement)

In the constructor of the form go

```
_car = new Car();
```

In the click method do

```
_car.Accelerate();
```

Comment: I tried this and nothing appeared in the list box. Thanks for trying!